# Tool for debugging makefiles

Tags: debugging, makefile

I have a large legacy codebase with very complicated makefiles, with lots of variables.  Sometimes I need to change them, and I find that it's very difficult to figure out why the change isn't working the way I expect.  What I'd like to find is a tool that basically does step-through-debugging of the "make" process, where I would give it a directory, and I would be able to see the value of different variables at different points in the process.  None of the debug flags to make seem to show me what I want, although it's possible that I'm missing something.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 82):

Have you been looking at the output from running `make -n` and `make -np`, and the biggie `make -nd`?

Are you using a fairly recent version of `gmake`?

Have you looked at the free chapter on [Debugging Makefiles](http://oreilly.com/catalog/make3/book/index.csp) available on O'Reilly's site for their excellent book "Managing Projects with GNU Make" ([Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101)).

Answer (score 40):

I'm sure that [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) is what you are looking for.

From the homepage:

> **remake** is a patched and modernized version of GNU make utility that adds improved error reporting, the ability to trace execution in a comprehensible way, and a debugger.

It has gdb-like interface and is supported by mdb-mode in (x)emacs which means breakponts, watches etc. And there's  [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) if you don't like (x)emacs

Comment: If I could I would add +100. When using remake ('brew install remake' for installation), the problem that I had to debug simply DISAPPEARED. No idea what the problem is, but who cares? :)

Answer (score 23):

From the man page on make command-line options:

```
-n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon  
Print the commands that would be executed, but do not execute them.  

-d  Print debugging information in addition to normal processing.  
The debugging information says  
which files are being considered for remaking,  
which file-times are being compared and with what results,  
which files actually need  to  be  remade,  
which implicit  rules are considered and which are applied---  
everything interesting about how make decides what to do.  

--debug[=FLAGS] Print debugging information in addition to normal processing.  
If the FLAGS are omitted, then the behaviour is the same as if -d was specified.  
FLAGS may be:  
'a' for all debugging output same as using -d,  
'b' for basic debugging,  
'v' for more verbose basic debugging,  
'i' for showing implicit rules,  
'j' for details on invocation of commands, and  
'm' for debugging while remaking makefiles.
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of any specific flag that does exactly what you want, but

```
--print-data-base
```

sounds like it might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

```
remake --debugger all
```

More info https://vimeo.com/97397484

https://github.com/rocky/remake/wiki/Installing

Answer (score 0):

There is a GNU make debugger project at http://gmd.sf.net which looks quite useful. The main feature supported by gmd is breakpointing, which may be more useful than stepping. To use this, you download gmd from http://gmd.sf.net and gmsl from http://gmsl.sf.net, and do an 'include gmd' in your makefile.