# Know what shell commands / recipes are executed with Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I execute Make, I'd like to know what shell commands / recipes are executed (and perhaps which line in which Makefile invoked these). Is there a way of doing this (print onto the stdout or write to a file) without modifying the Makefiles?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753/tool-for-debugging-makefiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands will be echoed to stdout by default, unless you disabled that by prefixing them with `@`.

A few options you can pass to make:

- `-n`: echos commands that *would* be run, but without running them. This will also echo commands that are prefixed with `@`.
- `-d`: print debug output. This will output the process that make goes through in attempting to find rules that match the targets that it's trying to make. There will be a lot of useless information in here, as it will try *many* default build rules (like how to build .o files from .c).
  There are a few ways to cut down on the noise:

  - `-r`: disable implicit rules. If you don't depend on any of the default rules , this can be used in conjunction with -d to just print the parts you (mostly) care about
  - `--debug=b`: basic debug mode. prints what it's trying to make, but not any information about implicit rules.

None of these print the line numbers of the commands, but `make -n --debug=b` will print both the targets being built and the commands being run, so it's almost as good. Example below.

**`$ cat makefile`**:

```
c: a b
    cat $^ > $@

a:
    echo 'foo' > $@

b: a
    cat $^ > $@
    echo 'bar' >> $@
```

**`$ make -n --debug=b`**:

```
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
   File 'a' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'a'.
echo 'foo' > a
  Successfully remade target file 'a'.
   File 'b' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'b'.
cat a > b
echo 'bar' >> b
  Successfully remade target file 'b'.
 Prerequisite 'a' is newer than target 'c'.
 Prerequisite 'b' is newer than target 'c'.
Must remake target 'c'.
cat a b > c
Successfully remade target file 'c'.
```