# How can I debug Makefile?

Tags: unix, makefile

How can debug Make file ? Which file does it match ? How can I print it ? How can I print all options(before match) ?

For example,

```
MY_FILE            = my_file

%.c: a.%.tcl | $(MY_FILE)   -@echo "[START] : $* "

    @source my_script   -@echo " [DONE ] : $* "
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002d_002ddebug)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tool for debugging makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753/tool-for-debugging-makefiles)

Comment: It's a black art

Comment: An internet search before asking a question is always a good start.